# Are upper triangular matrices with real entries associative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I'm trying to disprove that with a,b,c belonging to the real numbers, that the matrix \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0& c\end{bmatrix}

is NOT a group under matrix multiplication. With the criteria for a group being closure, identity, associativity, and inverse; I think that it fails associativity. Can someone explain this? Thanks in advance

Also I tried formatting the matrix as a $2\times2$ but under the preview it shows [a b
0  c] - Sorry about that

Comment: Associativity  is a general property of matrix product, why should it fail for a specific class of matrices?

Comment: Could you explain which property it would fail then? I had a similar problem dealing with matrix addition being a group, but under matrix multiplication I am more confused

Comment: What would be the inverse of the null matrix?

Comment: The inverse would be Row 1 [ d -b]

Comment: row 2 [0 a], sorry meant to put into one post. the determinant would be ad right? how does that fail

Comment: An upper  triangular matrix is not necessarily invertible.

Comment: Does it only fail when either a or d is 0? Would that make it invertible since the determinate would be 0? Thanks

Comment: I used the wrongs variables, not d but a or c

Answer (score 0):

A square matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is not zero. Hence for your problem you have that matrices with either $a_{11}=0$ and/or $a_{22}=0$ are not invertible since $\text{det}(A)=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{21}a_{12}$. In fact those are the only non invertible matrices (since $a_{21}$ is always zero), since assuming $a_{11}\neq 0 \neq a_{22}$ you would obtain $\text{det}(A)\neq 0$ and thus $A$ would be invertible (in $\text{Mat}_{2 \times2}(k)$). However one needs to point out that your inverse would have be an upper triangular matrix as well in order for $G$ to be a group (pretending we don't know that its not), which implies that $\text{det}(A) \neq 0$ is not necessarily sufficient for $A$ to have an inverse in $G$ (since $\text{det}(A) \neq 0$ only ensures that it is invertible in $\text{Mat}_{2 \times2}(k)$).